# Bidirectional Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, analog

I was reading a paper where one of the components mention is a bidirectional amplifier that is a voltage-voltage (VCVS) amplifier in the forward direction and current-current (CCCS) direction in the backward direction. To be more specific, if \$V_1\$ is the voltage at the input side and \$I_1\$ is the current at the input side, then:

$$V_2 = A \cdot V_1$$
$$I_2 = A \cdot I_1$$

I do know that there are various feedback topologies that can be used in design of amplifiers but I have very little knowledge regarding the design of bidirectional amplifiers. For instance, designing a voltage-voltage amplifier is quite straigh-forward. It seems that we would need to sense the voltage at the output, convert it to current, and then pass it through a gain of \$\frac{1}{A}\$ to get \$I_1\$. Does this make sense ?

Comment: *For instance, designing a voltage-voltage amplifier is quite straight-forward* It can be, but if the requirements are tough it might still be difficult to impossible. *It seems that we would need to sense the voltage at the output, convert it to current* **Why?** You only define voltage-to-voltage and current-to-current relations. So I'd say that to implement the 2 equations you show, we need to sense \$I_1\$, multiply its value by \$A\$ resulting in \$I_2\$.

Comment: Basically anything can be designed / made but do realize that **how the device is used** can have an impact on how it behaves. For example: a current output that has no load but still outputs a current will have its voltage rise to infinity (theoretically), if that voltage is then sensed and amplified, the "other side" of the device would also reach an infinite voltage. This can result in a not working solution and/or oscillations. So how the device is used, with what loads etc. is important.

Comment: You asked why we would need to sense \$I_2\$. This is a paper on analog neural networks. Basically, the task of backpropagation is performed by injecting current in the output nodes. The circuit senses the changes in the output nodes and adjusts itself accordingly. I don't want to go into too much details, but that's basically the idea. Do you know of any resource I can look at that might give me place to start with regards to designing such an amplifier. I would like to do a SPICE simulation and see how things work.

Comment: Do you mean \$V_2=A_V\cdot V_1\$ and \$I_1=A_I\cdot I_2\$ ? You did say, "a voltage-voltage (VCVS) amplifier in the forward direction and current-current (CCCS) direction in the backward direction."

Comment: Its seems a bit like you're taking a roundabout route to describe the behavior of a transformer ...